# Display results of MYSQL in PHP properly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple quiz PHP app and I have an SQL query that returns the following results:

```
question_id | question_title | answer_title
   1        |   your name?   |   michael
   1        |   your name?   |   samuel
   2        |   your age?    |    20
   2        |   your age?    |    21
   2        |   your age?    |    23
```

Now I want to display each question with its answers in format like this:

```
<div class="question">
     <div>your name?</div>
     <div class="answer">michael</div>
     <div class="answer">samuel</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
     <div>your age?</div>
     <div class="answer">20</div>
     <div class="answer">21</div>
     <div class="answer">22</div>
</div>
```

I'm using PDO to display MYSQL results. The problem if I loop through the MYSQL results, a question will be displayed multiple times as It's returned in each row. Also don't know how to add the closing DIV tag for the question class after all answers for a certain question are displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class and function, as such:

```
<?php
class GetInfo {
    public static function GetData() {
        $link = new mysqli();
        $link->real_connect($hostName, $username, $password, $databaseName);

        $rs = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `table`;");
        print "<table>";
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
            print "<tr>";
                print "<td>" . $result['questionColumn'] . " = " . $result['answerColumn'] . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
        }
        print "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

And then call it as so:

```
GetInfo::GetData();
```

I hope this helps you :)

(Sorry it's not PDO, I don't know PDO very well so it would be wrong of me to assume :) )

**EDIT**

```
<?php
class GetInfo {
    public static function GetData() {
        $link = new mysqli();
        $link->real_connect($hostName, $username, $password, $databaseName);

        $rs = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `table`;");
        print "<table>";
        $last = "";
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
            print "<tr>";
            $printing = ($last != $result['questionColumn'] ? $result['questionColumn'] : "";
                print "<td>" . $printing . " = " . $result['answerColumn'] . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            $last = $result['questionColumn'];
        }
        print "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem. It will display the same question multiple times. I want it to display a question only once and all answers under it and and the question/answer combo wrapped in a question class

Comment: Using this will remove that because of the fetch assoc, each result shows once, that or you have the same question/answer combo in which use use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` in your query

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` will make the query display only one answer per question not all the answers

Comment: Using mysqli_fecth_assoc steps through each row one at a time, no rows are traversed ore than once - meaning, the only way this would produce the same results is if you have more that one of each result in the database. Using mysqli_fetch_assoc will do the code in the while almost like saying: `foreach ($row as $key=>$value) { print "{$key} = {$value}";  }`. mysqli_fetch_assoc never uses the same row twice [see here][http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php]

Comment: I'm not sure about this as I use PDO not MYSQLi. Also I don't have multiple rows. Each row has a different answer but multiple rows belong to the same question. So I can't skip rows. Hope it's clear

Comment: @MichaelSamuel, please see the edit, I have added a check to see if the last question has been used or not. I know this is not PDO, but surely they cannot be too dissimilar to use the theory from this in PDO?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is group all the answers for each question in a multiple dimension array. Try something like this:

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$query = ''; // query to run.
$answers = array();
foreach ($conn->query($query) as $row)
{
    $answers[$row['question_id']][] = $row['answer_title'];
}
```

Then you can do a foreach inside a foreach:

```
foreach ($answers as $question => $arr)
{
    echo '<tr><td>Question: '.$question.'</td><td>Answers: ';
    foreach ($arr as $i => $answer)
    {
        echo ($i > 0 ? ', ' : '').$answer;
    }
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: the array is printing numbers without the question title or answer title

Comment: What numbers? I can't see your screen remember. Surely you should be able to work out what you need to put in the array from what I've given you if it's not 100% right.

Comment: the first array is not printing the text in rows...seems like it is printing only keys

Comment: That'll be because I stored it by the question ID. Can't you think of a way to get the question to output? It's fairly simple,

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$qArr =  array(
    array(
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "your name",
        "ans" => "michael"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "your nam?",
        "ans" => "samuel"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "your age",
        "ans" => "20"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "your ag?",
        "ans" => "21"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "your age",
        "ans" => "22"
    )
); 

$flagLast = false;
$prevQuestionId = "";

foreach($qArr as $infoArr) {
    $questionId = $infoArr['id'];
    $title = $infoArr['title'];
    $ans = $infoArr['ans'];

    if($prevQuestionId != $questionId) {
        if($flagLast) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="question">';
        echo '<div>' . $title . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="answer">' .  $ans .  '</div>';
        $prevQuestionId = $questionId;
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="answer">' .  $ans .  '</div>';
        $flagLast = true;
    }
} 
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can fetch the records Order by question id. Also you have to define one PrevQuestionID outside the loop.

Check if the PrevQuestionID is not the Current QuestionId then Print the Question and assigned the Current QuestionId to  PrevQuestionID.

This will work for you

Comment: can you explain with code? I'm really fed up with this. Either question one not getting printed at all or one answer is shifted to another question. I can't really get it to work well

Comment: Please check the Post i have added and its working code. Instead of DB am fetching from an array. Please note that while fetching the record fetch it in order by question id